# ZPL Barcode missing front 2 digit

Tags: label, barcode, zebra-printers, zpl, barcode-printing

I am trying to print an EAN barcode vertically on a label with below ZPL code:

```
^FO895,273^BY3^BUB,200,Y,N
^FO895,261^FD9827755779090^FS
```

I'm expecting the output as **9827755779090**. However, it prints out as ***277557790900***.

It cuts off the first 2 digit(98) and adds (0) on the final digit. Can I know how do I fix my code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`^BE` is the EAN command. It will calculate the check digit for you.

> ^BE; EAN-13 Bar Code. Description: The ^BE command is similar to the
> UPC-A bar code. It is widely used throughout Europe and Japan in the
> retail marketplace. The EAN-13 bar code has 12 data characters, one
> more data character than the UPC-A code. An EAN-13 symbol contains the
> same number of bars as the UPC-A, but encodes a 13th digit into a
> parity pattern of the left-hand six digits. This 13th digit, in
> combination with the 12th digit, represents a country code. • ^BE
> supports fixed print ratios. • Field data (^FD) is limited to exactly
> 12 characters. ZPL II automatically truncates or pads on the left with
> zeros to achieve the required number of characters.

Here is the fixed code (with changed ^FO).

```
^XA
^FO95,273^BY3^BEB,200,Y,N
^FD9827755779090^FS
^XZ
```

Answer (score 1):

You are feeding the barcode more data than the specification is set for.

Plus, you are not creating an EAN code, but a UPC(12).

[Specification](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universal_Product_Code) :

> UPC (technically refers to UPC-A) consists of 12 digits

[Specification of ZPL II](https://support.zebra.com/cpws/docs/zpl/1994_46469lr1.pdf) on UPC-A  (code `^BU`) section 5.34 specifically states:

> `^FD` : exactly 11 characters. ZPL II auto-truncates or pads *ON THE LEFT* with 0 to achieve required number of characters.

(I added italics)

So you get

```
^FO895,261^FD9827755779090^FS
               -----------  << these 11 digits
```

It just so happens that the UPC checksum of `27755779090` is `0`

This is why you would get same result for `^FO895,261^FD999999988889827755779090^FS`

To get exactly what you want, use

```
^FO895,261^FD98277557790^FS
```

.. this will get a checksum of `4`